# How to change the dtype of data in tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I have a dataset loaded from a directory using this API

```
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.3,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

And I want to change the data type and to make the training faster

I tried this but it didn't work

```
for image_batch, labels_batch in train_ds:
  image_batch = tf.cast(image_batch,tf.int16)
```

Comment: You should not convert your `x` to `int` type (a chance to encounter numerical instability) rather you should consider using the **mixed-precision** technique for faster training.

Comment: How I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just apply [map](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) method for your dataset(s):

```
val_ds.map(lambda x, y: (tf.cast(x, tf.int16), y))
```